# How to SELF JOIN?

Tags: mysql, sql

How to get cross record for this?

No|  depart |  arrive  | price
1 | BDO     |  **DPS** | 1100000
2 | **DPS** |  AMQ     | 800000

> output must be : **DPS**

Thanks.

-Asep-

Comment: question isn't clear.

Comment: would you like to have only records which consist `DPS`?

Comment: so, what sql query must i do?

Comment: mj5 - yes, please.

Comment: `select * from table_name where depart = 'DPS' or arrive = 'DPS'` may help you.. do google before ask your question, my friend. Walaikum assalam wa rahmatullah

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a self-join:

```
SELECT DISTINCT t1.depart
FROM mytable AS t1
JOIN mytable As t2 ON t1.depart = t2.arrive
```

Answer (score 1):

from your comments, a simple `select` might help you to find the records, which consist DPS.

```
SELECT * FROM your_table_name where depart = 'DPS' or arrive = 'DPS'
```